# Need to click on input twice to see result

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a function to fetch the number of tags of a specific id on a page but need to click twice on the input in order to get the results to display. The actual filtering works on the first click but the number of results displaying only refreshes if I click the same input a second time once the page reloads. Below is the code I am using to designate the function and then call it. Any insight would be helpful.

```
function elementCount(){
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.box-shodow-container').length;
var y = x - 1;
document.getElementById('resource-count').innerHTML=y;

}
<input type="checkbox"  onClick="elementCount()" value="Ask the Expert" name="apf" class="checkbox-primary"   />
```

Comment: Can you create a code snippet/jsfiddle replicating this, I wasn't able to.

Comment: Dan share full code please

Comment: I don't see any problems with that code.  It outputs -1, as expected.

Comment: Code working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9uth9ke9/1/